# Integer representatives for $F^{\times} / N_{E/F}(E^{\times})$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-numbers

It's been a while since algebraic number theory, so I apologize if this is too simple.

Let $F=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{s})$ and $E=F(i\sqrt{t})$, where $s,t > 0$ are square-free integers. I would like to find a positive integer representative for the nontrivial class in $F^{\times} / N_{E/F}(E^{\times})$ (I think there are only two classes anyway). When $s$ is a square, I seem to recall that any prime $p$ not dividing $t$ suffices, but I can't find a source for that.

Any help is appreciated.

In fact, even just working a relatively simple case of $s=3$, $t=1$ would be nice.

Comment: Are you sure this is the question you want to ask? This quotient will always be an infinite group. If $F$ was a finite extension of $\mathbf{Q}_p$ and $E/F$ was a quadratic extension, then $E^{\times}/N_{E/F}(E^{\times})$ is always isomorphic to a group of order two (indeed the group $\mathrm{Gal}(E/F)$) by local class field theory. There is an analog for number fields, but the correct formulation involves the idele class group.

Comment: This is indeed the question I want to ask. I'm reading some (incomplete) notes on arithmetic lattices in $\operatorname{SU}(H)$, where $H$ is a Hermitian matrix with coefficients in $E/F$, a CM-field. At some point the author writes "Without loss of generality, assume $\det(H)$ represents **the** nontrivial class in $F^{\times}/N_{E/F}(E^{\times})$" [emphasis mine]. My hope was to get my hands on a representative in this simpler bi-quadratic case and then play around with some lattices.

Comment: To see when $p$ or $\alpha$ is a norm look at factorization of prime ideals, look at the size of the residue field and if they are principals

Comment: Why do you say "This is indeed the question I want to ask" and then go on to say that your actual interest is in finding examples of arithmetic lattices? My first suggestion is to consider the group $G = \mathbf{Q}^{\times}/N_{\mathbf{Q}(i)/\mathbf{Q}}(\mathbf{Q}(i)^{\times})$. This is $\mathbf{Q}^{\times}$  modulo rational numbers which are the sum of two squares. Then convince yourself that none of $3$, $7$, or $3 \cdot 7$ (or any product of distinct primes which are $3 \pmod 4$, let alone their negatives) is the sum of two squares. So $G$ is infinite.

Comment: Well crud, you're right. Thanks. I guess I'll have to reach out to the author now about these notes as this infinite quotient drastically changes a few results in there.